# drawAtPoint not working for PDF OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf

CGContextShowTextAtPoint is saying that it is deprecated, so I would like to find an alternative for drawing text to a PDF context. The following works (which is the code that I would like to change):

```
CGPDFContextBeginPage(self.writeContext, pageDictionary);

 //Add text
 CGContextSelectFont(self.writeContext, "Helvetica", 26, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
 CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(self.writeContext, kCGTextFill);
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(self.writeContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
 const char *text="Hello Text Test";
 CGContextShowTextAtPoint(self.writeContext, 110, 0, text, strlen(text));

 CGPDFContextEndPage(self.writeContext);
```

But this code does not work (the page ends up just being blank)

```
CGPDFContextBeginPage(self.writeContext, pageDictionary);

 //Add text
[@"Hello Text Test" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]}];
 //=========

CGPDFContextEndPage(self.writeContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the NSGraphicsContext

full Code snippet below:

```
NSLog(@"Print PDF");
CFURLRef filePath;
NSSavePanel*    panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[panel setNameFieldStringValue:[self.selectedAccount.name stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"]];
[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

        NSURL*  theFile = [panel URL];
        CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 576.0, 576.0);
        CFURLRef saveLocation = CFBridgingRetain(theFile);
        //dictionary to store doc attributes
        CFMutableDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,
                                                                      3,
                                                                      &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                                      &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

        CFDictionaryAddValue(attributes, kCGPDFContextAuthor, CFSTR("Rich Claxton"));
        CFDictionaryAddValue(attributes, kCGPDFContextTitle, CFSTR("This is working"));

        CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(saveLocation, &mediaBox, attributes);

        /** Create NSGraphicsContext !! **/
        NSGraphicsContext* newGC = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:pdfContext flipped:NO];
        [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
        [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:newGC];


        CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);

        //Draw Strings here
        [@"Hello World !!" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(2.0,2.0) withAttributes:(NULL)];

        CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
        CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
        CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
    }
}];
```